# Setting up Foreign keys in myPhpAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to create 3 tables but I keep getting an error in my SQL syntax, particularly the foreign key syntax.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Personal_trainer (
employee_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id INT FOREIGN KEY,
supervisor_id INT FOREIGN KEY,
Centre_id INT FOREIGN KEY,
First_name varchar(20),
Last_name varchar(20),
Postcode varchar(10),
Address varchar(50))

CREATE TABLE Supervisor (
supervisor_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
employee_id INT FOREIGN KEY,
Centre_id INT FOREIGN KEY, 
First_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(20))

CREATE TABLE Gym (
centre_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
supervisor_id INT FOREIGN KEY,
location varchar(30)
Postcode varchar(10));
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/5.7/en/example-foreign-keys.html

Comment: If you have a `FOREIGN KEY` you need to supply what that Key *is referencing*. Like saying "I went somewhere foreign on my holiday" , you need to tell your MySQL table WHERE you went! "I went to Mars on my holiday".

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.  MySQL is expecting a reference to the table and column that makes a particular column a foreign key.  This is done at the end of the table definition after you've defined the columns, so for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Personal_trainer (
employee_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id INT, 
...
FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id),
```

Comment: can you explain/clarify the `...` you used for `customer_id`?

Comment: ... just means, whatever other column definitions you already had.

Comment: the placement of it on the same line implied it was relative to that data, so I've put it on a new line to imply other columns etc.

Comment: @Martin thumbsup